# Which component of the dielectric tensor is used in generating EELS in TDDFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, spectroscopy, td-dft, optical-properties

[Electron Energy Loss Spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_energy_loss_spectroscopy) (EELS) comes from the imaginary part of the inverse dielectric function $-\text{Im}[\varepsilon^{-1}(q, \omega)]$. If the dielectric function is actually a tensor and there is anisotropy, which component of the tensor is used to generate EELS in calculations or, alternatively, what appears in EELS experimentally?

Comment: Don't know very much about EELS specifically so take this with a grain of salt, but for other types of spectroscopy like optical rotation, the observed effect would be related to the trace of your tensor for a randomly oriented material. If you had an oriented sample, you could make measures along different facets to resolve each of the components of the tensor.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer? Was the comment by Tyberius helpful?